# Query returns wrong row using joins even if where clause denies it

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count rows but the problem is that it returns rows what is described in my where clause not to include.

This query should return number of networks that has at least one row in `network_logs` table and the `network_log` row must be with type "ENTRANCE" and with status_code 0 but for some reason, it returns rows that has different type also.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id AND nl.type = "ENTRANCE" AND nl.status_code = 0
WHERE n.status_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59' AND nl.created_at
BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59'
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(nl.id) >= 1;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using 2020-07-31 00:00:59?  That is quite arcane.

Answer (score 0):

I'd review the where clause to use the right priority on the AND

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id AND nl.type = "ENTRANCE" AND nl.status_code = 0
WHERE 
    n.status_time BETWEEN ('2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59') 
AND 
    nl.created_at BETWEEN ('2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59')
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING COUNT(nl.id) >= 1;
```

without sample data and expected results this is untested. It may be that you have to review the outer and to become an OR imho but without sample data it is impossible to understand

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count 
FROM networks as n
INNER JOIN network_sessions AS ns ON ns.network_id = n.id
JOIN network_logs AS nl ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id 

WHERE n.status_time BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59' 
AND nl.created_at BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 00:00:59'
AND nl.type = "ENTRANCE" AND nl.status_code = 0
```

as network_logs contain at least 1 value so you can apply inner join and no need count()

Answer (score 0):

> This query should return number of networks that has at least one row in network_logs table and the network_log row must be with type "ENTRANCE" and with status_code 0

These conditions are in the `ON` clause for a `LEFT JOIN`.  If you really want to filter by them, then use an `INNER JOIN` -- and/or move the conditions to the `WHERE` clause.

I also suspect that you want all rows in July -- not just up to the first minute on the last day.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id as test_count 
FROM networks n JOIN
     network_sessions ns
     ON ns.network_id = n.id JOIN
     network_logs nl
     ON nl.network_session_id = ns.id
WHERE nl.type = 'ENTRANCE' AND nl.status_code = 0 AND
      n.status_time >= '2020-07-01' AND 
      n.status_time < '2020-08-01' AND 
      nl.created_at >= '2020-07-01' AND
      nl.created_at < '2020-08-01' ;
```